# How can I establish a reverse connection from phone to PC via adb

Tags: android, adb

Unfortunately, it is difficult to find information on my question, as there is a command `adb reverse`, which is the opposite of `adb forward` and jams up the search results. But I'm looking for the `adb connect` command in the "opposite" direction.

So, the task. I have a server with a public IP. My phone is connected to a VPN/Proxy, its IP can change from time to time. How can I initialize the adb connect process from a device to a public and known ip address? One way is to use VPN to create a local network, but the device is already connected to another server's VPN. Therefore, this option is not suitable for me. Are there any alternatives?

UPD: My phone is rooted, such solutions are fine.

Comment: Note that adb is a plaintext protocol like telnet so I strongly recommend not to use it through insecure networks or the Internet. May be in your case ssh would be a better alternative. An ssh client on Android connects to a server somewhere and ssh has also very good port forwarding capabilities in both directions.

Comment: Thank you, I just created reverse SSH tunnel (using Termux apk from F-Droid as Google Play contains only deprecated version) and it seems to be exactly what I need)